# Some files from my Subversion repository have their content written twice. What can I do?

Tags: svn, jenkins

Question title says quite the whole. Anyway, let me be a little more precise.

Those java files come from a branch that I merged into my trunk.

When I check them out in Eclipse, they appear correct. But when Jenkins check them out, the content is doubled and a file that initially contained

```
public enum Properties {
    type("type"),
    kind("kind"), 
    value("value");
}
```

Appear as

```
public enum Properties {
    type("type"),
    kind("kind"), 
    value("value");
}
public enum Properties {
    type("type"),
    kind("kind"), 
    value("value");
}
```

So, what is the problem ? and what can i do to solve it ?

**EDIT** when i say file is correct with Eclipse, I may not be clear : in the workspace i use, the file is correct for Eclipse and for Maven. But when checked out by Jenkins, the file always appear errorneous.

Comment: Check with another editor than eclipse if the file is correct or not.

Comment: Test with pure SVN CLI-client `svn cat URL_TO_FILE`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This appears to be a known bug: [#JENKINS-14551: an update which contains added files merged from a branch results in those files having doubled content](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-14551). It seems to be a problem in the Jenkins Subversion plugin.

The workaround is to change the SVN update policy of the Jenkins job to always check out a clean copy.

Answer (score 3):

Try going into the project in Jenkins and choosing the Wipe Out Workspace option under Workspace on the left-hand menu.

We are experiencing the same issue.  It seems to be working for us.
I can't tell for sure yet, but I think once I have done this on a project, we don't run into it again.  If this is the case, I suspect it has to do with either upgrading SVN or upgrading the Jenkins SVN plugin and the working copy somehow missing or having some extra metadata.